# Where to find linguistic tips on quranic translations?

Tags: arabic, quran-translation, translation, language

I'm trying to read Quran, and I need to be able to understand the original Arabic at some places. For example, the verse that says:

إِنَّكَ لَمِنَ الْمُرْسَلِينَ

You see in many places that it's been translated as "you're truly one of the messengers".

Now I can map "truly" to "innaka", and "one of the messengers" to "minalmorsalin". However I fail to understand what "la" means there. I Googled around and found that "li" means belonging to, yet that's far from what I see here.

Do we have a website that explains translations, presents etymology, gives lingual rules, and provides tips on hermeneutics, instead of merly presenting the final product?

Comment: "la" mentioned here is used to emphasize what is said, not in the meaning of "li" (to)

Comment: @Ziyad, is there a reference out there that talks and explains just the way you did in your comment?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://corpus.quran.com/treebank.jsp?chapter=2&verse=252&token=7

Comment: @afnrf, exactly. Please post it as an answer, so that I can mark it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this website for the verse you mentioned: http://corpus.quran.com/treebank.jsp?chapter=2&verse=252&token=7

It diagrammatically shows the grammatical construction of Quranic verses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn/study Arabic. I have seen few free videos of Maulana Nouman Ali. There are great. He has a excellent course on it. You can check his website - http://bayyinah.com/.